# Canon EDSDK 2.11 on OSX EdsOpenSession exc_bad_access

Tags: macos, sdk, exc-bad-access, openframeworks, edsdk

I'm trying to use the Canon EDSDK 2.11 on OSX with a EOS Xsi. I tried running the sample code, I've written my own code, and I even downloaded openFrameworks and an add-on for the Canon EDSK, ofxCanon, and ran its sample code. Every time any of the code reaches a call to EdsOpenSession I get a `exc_bad_access` error.

Can anyone tell me what might be going on and what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: speculation: exc_bad_access is usually associated with accessing an array element that does not exist.  This leads me to believe that some data structure that is an array of available cameras has a length/size of zero and your code is trying to access an element from it.  Again speculation, but your camera probably isn't seen in the list of available devices.  Try a new cable?  Try a different Canon camera?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems there is some issues with the SDK downloaded from Canon site. 
Here what you can try, it solved the problem for me.

Install and update EOSUtility (make sure it works)

Go to /Applications/Canon Utilities/

Show Package Content of EOS Utility.

In frameworks directory you will have EDSDK.framework

Copy it over the one you got from Canon site.

Hope it will help.