# EDSDK EdsOpenSession EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal

Tags: macos, edsdk, canon-sdk

I believe this is similar to the thread: [Canon SDK 2.11 on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637670/canon-edsdk-2-11-on-osx-edsopensession-exc-bad-access)

However the solution there did not work for me.  I'm perplexed because I'm not sure how to figure out what has changed.  I had some working software, did not work on it over the holiday and now when I open it up to work it fails.  Not only my software but the demo app included with the SDK, which I have never changed and indeed used to work just fine.

I have tried with two different cameras (5DmII and 5DmIII) with the same result.

when I try and run the application, the camera is recognized but, as it attempts to open a session it receives a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.  In each program it happens when a call is made to EdsOpenSession() with this message...

*** -[NSConcreteData release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8157af0

Interestingly, when I tried to use the EOS Utility that would crash also.  So I updated and now that works great.  I followed the suggestion in the above thread and copied the EDSDK.framework from the working bundle to my program and recompiled but I get the same results.

I'm trying to figure out how to contact Canon to get some information but they don't make it easy to get help so I'm appealing to the one group I know is responsive.

The only thing I can think is that sometime over the holiday I updated some critical library without knowing it.

Has anyone else run into and been able to solve this?

I'm running OS X 10.7.5, xcode 4.1, and EDSDK 2.11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.   It did turn out to be the same solution as the mentioned link.  However, what I was missing was that I needed to also copy the new EDSDK.framework into /Library/Frameworks not just have it in my source directory.  This may be because I don't have everything setup correctly in XCode.